# Start command line with parameters and collection output

Tags: c#, command-line

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
//startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "tsvc -a -st rifs -h "+textBox1+" -sn "+textBox2+" -status";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

richTextBox1.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

1. I need to run a command in `cmd` that will take 2 parameters that will be inserted to textBox1 and textBox2 and then sending the output to the richTextBox1.
2. When running it this way I get :

   > first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
   >   Additional information: StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet
3. I tried to exclude the Output line , and when i do it does run CMD but does not type in any command (It just opens a CMD window and does nothing ) .

Answer (score 1):

`Process.Start()` asynchronously starts a new process.  When you get to the `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` the process is not finished yet, thus the exception.  You should use eventing to hook into the OutputDataRecieved event.  You want to do something like this:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/c tsvc -a -st rifs -h " + textBox1 + " -sn " + textBox2 + " -status";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOnOutputDataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessOnOutputDataReceived;
        process.Start();
```

and then add an event handler to the Output data recieved like so:

```
    private void ProcessOnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += dataReceivedEventArgs.Data;
    }
```

Also, I am not certain but i think you need to call text on your textboxes:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c tsvc -a -st rifs -h " + textBox1.Text + " -sn " + textBox2.Text + " -status";
```

Comment: I tried it your way , but when adding the Event handler it does not recognizes the richTextBox1.

Also when excluding the output lines , it still just opens a CMD window without running any command .

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't recognize? does it throw an exception or are you getting a compile time error?

Comment: Compile time error :
D:\Liveperson\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NOC ToolBox\NOC ToolBox\RifsManager.cs(59,12): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NOC_ToolBox.RifsManager.richTextBox1'
D:\Liveperson\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NOC ToolBox\NOC ToolBox\RifsManager.Designer.cs(162,50): (Related location)

Comment: my bad.  remove the static from the event handler. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: I think you also need to explicitly redirect your standard output.  Ill edit my answer again.

Comment: Well i tried this , and now it just crashes without even giving an error , i just get a window saying "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams." 
with an option to continue or break

Comment: OK i edited my answer again.  I also set the CreateNoWindow property to true.  It looked like you might be trying to hide the window.  if you want to show the window comment out that line.

Comment: Ok , no errors now , but no output on the richTextBox ether, but when i out the line that hides the window the window appears and disappears too fast for me to see if any command typed in .

Comment: You might be getting an error from the process.  you can try to hook into the error data and put a breakpoint in the event handler.  I will add that to the answer as well.

Comment: Same thing , But shouldn't it send the output to the Text box even if the CMD returned an error?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it in the End with .

```
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        int counter = 0 ,totalMemory=0;
        string line;
        string command = " /c ro -a -h " + textBox1.Text + " -sn HC* $$info Server Total = $servermemory Service Memory = $servicememory > c:\\noc\\ntb\\logs\\output.txt";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);
        Process proc = new Process();
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```