# Error while executing command via cmd in C#

Tags: c#, process

I'm using C# and I need to execute `command` in cmd without displaying shell window and retrieve the result, so I did some work like the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

proc.Start();
string output = string.Empty;
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```

But when I executed this code, console returned me this error: **'System.InvalidOperationException'(System.dll)**.

Why is this problem happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start command line with parameters and collection output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001572/start-command-line-with-parameters-and-collection-output)

Comment: @MuratGündeş Oh it worked for me, but are there parameters that can make `proc` to wait until the whole process is finished? `command` is a command that requires time to complete and this code won't wait for me.